# ntp.conf sync to local machines

Tags: linux, ntp

I have 2 linux machines, they do not have internet connectivity or any other means of getting an external clock.

I need one of them to act as the "master"/server and the other machine to sync it's clock to that server. It's not important that the time is correct, it's only important that the time is the same on these 2 machines.

So, give I have a server (192.168.1.10) and a client (192.168.1.11), how do I set up /etc/ntp.conf on these 2 machines respectivly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is, on the master, tell it to use the system clock (which has a "fake" IP address of 127.127.1.0) as a reference clock, and use the `fudge` option to assign that to a stratum.  If you'll never connect to the Internet, it doesn't really matter what stratum you assign.  Then tell the slave(s) to use the master as their server.

[Using NTP without access to the Internet](http://docsrv.sco.com/NET_tcpip/ntpT.no_inet.html) gives concrete examples of the syntax.